# What's the best way to get the Product information using opportunity line item?

Tags: opportunity-lineitem

I want to get the product information using Opportunity line Item.What is the simplest way to query this?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SOQL allows you to traverse object relationships using dot notation, so for example to get to the Product (and its fields) via the Pricebook on the OpportunityLine you can do this...

```
Select PricebookEntry.Product2.Name From OpportunityLineItem
```

Then in Apex use the same path to access the field you need.

```
String productName = queriedOppLine.Product2.Name;
```